# What is the source of error in this mBJ-LDA calculation?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, band-structure

I am trying to do MBJLDA calculation for bandstructure for WS2 monolayer unit cell using VASP and following the method provided here : [Band Structure mBJ-LDA using Vasp](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1997/band-structure-mbj-lda-using-vasp), but I am getting an error message.
The INPUTS are below:

INCAR:

```
ENCUT=600
PREC = Accurate
EDIFF=1E-6
NELM=300
ISMEAR=-5

###MBJ:
METAGGA=MBJ
LASPH=.TRUE.
LMAXMIX=4
GGA=CA
```

LDA POTCAR:

```
  PAW W_pv 06Nov2007                     
   TITEL  = PAW W_pv 06Nov2007
  PAW S 27Mar2009                        
   TITEL  = PAW S 27Mar2009
```

POSCAR:

```
 W2S4                                   
   1.00000000000000     
     3.1912863255000001    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
    -1.5956425563000001    2.7637348281000000    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   20.1269199999999984
   W    S 
     1     2
Direct
  0.6666670084824631  0.3333329922369330  0.5000000000000000
  0.3333330949386806  0.6666670699615054  0.4218851941843354
  0.3333330949386806  0.6666670699615054  0.5781148058156645
 
  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
```

**The calculations was based on SCF-PBE WAVECAR**.
[image: ERROR]

Comment: Is that the end of the error message?

Comment: This is all what it is shown.

Comment: I suggest you first repeat the result of the linked tutorial with a 3D semiconductortor.

Comment: Following the linked tutorial, I can't repeat your error.

Comment: It should be noted that the MBJ-LDA method for 2D materials is tricky to obtain converged results.

Comment: +1. Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/391/5 and https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1470/5. A little more on mBJ: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1048/5.

Comment: Could you show the whole calculation flow to repeat your error message?

Comment: The calculations doesn't even started, this is the whole error message. Could you please try to repeat it with the inputs mentioned above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that:

- You really care about is how to calculate the MBJ band structure of monolayer WS2.
- You can follow the linked answer: [mBJ-LDA band structure calculation using VASP](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1997/mbj-lda-band-structure-calculation-using-vasp)

For monolayer, it is very hard/tricky to converge at MBJ self-consistent calculation. Usually, one possible way is you can obtain the CMBJ=XXX from its bulk counterpart.

I have tried this but get unsatisfactory result:

- Bulk WS2 (SOC is ignored!):

  - PBE band:
    [image]
  - MBJ band:
    [image]

    ```
    grep CMBJ OUTCAR ====> CMBJ=1.2327
    ```
- Monolayer WS2:

  - PBE result:
    [image]
  - MBJ result:
    [image]

    #### INCAR

    ```
     ### Read PBE wavefunction
     ISTART=1
     ICHARG=0
     ENCUT=400
     EDIFF=1E-6
     NELM=300
     ISMEAR=-5

     ###MBJ:
     METAGGA=MBJ
     LASPH=.TRUE.
     LMAXMIX=4
     GGA=CA
     CMBJ=1.2327
    ```

This unsatisfactory result may be related to the badly converged MBJ self-consistent calculation. Unfortunately, I haven't found any solutions for this (still trying...).

By the way, the system contains only three atoms, why not using the HSE06 method?

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am also getting the same error for a bulk material, my system is quite big. I am not sure how did you fix the question asked by Chi kou. Like I know that setting a value for CBMJ helps with convergence but I do not have any value for my specific case and I have tried a few values none of which helo this issue ? Furthermore, I do not get this error in PBE so this should be something related to mBJ only.

Comment: So actually my issue went away if I simply did not put ISMEAR = -5 in my INCAR. But very confused as to why this problem was happening in the first place.